Overflow but visible
How do you create a vertically scrollable region where the items are visible outside the container?
I've created a MRE to help you. For example, how do you get the inner green box to be visible outside the main container?


.outer {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 15px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class=outer>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item>
      <div class=inner></div>
    </div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
    <div class=item></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



There's an existing question but it does not answer my question because it's using an overlay.

Can you explain more about what you are trying to achieve?

I think anyone would assume that as there are separate overflow properties for each axis, that these properties would be indepedent. But alas, that is not the case.
Your code is as follows:
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: visible;

If you read the CSS specification which defines the overflow properties, you’ll see this paragraph near the bottom of the section:

The visible/clip values of overflow compute to auto/hidden
(respectively) if one of overflow-x or overflow-y is neither visible
nor clip.

It’s a little hard to understand this paragraph at first, but if you set overflow-y: scroll, then overflow-x: visible computes to overflow-x: auto. Basically you cannot have scrolling overflow in one axis and visible overflow in the other axis. It’s prohibited by the specification.

Ok, how do you achieve this effect—possibly with JavaScript?
